# Method parameter or instance attribute?

Tags: python, oop

Sometimes when I am designing a new method for a class that needs to act on certain variable, I can't say if it's better to pass this variable as a method parameter or if it's better to save this variable as an instance attribute and just use it inside the method. What are the advantages/disadvantages of both approaches?

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
    def my_method(self):
        # does something with self.data
```

Or

```
class B:
    def my_method(self, data):
        # does something with data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on all the other things the class may do.

Most generally, what is the abstraction that your class encapsulates?

Does it need `data` for lots of operations, or only this? Will `data` change? If `data` is the "point" of this class, then it should probably be in the `__init__`, but if it uses `data` to *act on* the object, then probably not.

We need to know more....